# Re-Transition when I click on button (e.g./i.e. Like Intent from current Activity to self Activity)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, firebase-realtime-database, activity-transition

Basically I am working on Google Map in which I have Google Map Activity and user click on any place of Google Map I was adding marker on this click and I have one button on this button click I take this marker position and put it to my Firebase Database.My complete code was working, but the problem is that when I click on the button which takes marker latlang to Firebase, my latlang value successfully update and my map Activity is re-transited (e.g./i.e. like Intent from current Activity to self Activity) that for my map was reloaded and I lose marker on screen.

Here is my Java code:

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class PickUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, View.OnClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public double marker_latitude;
    public double marker_longitude;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private Marker marker;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private Button btn;
    private Bus bus;
    private Firebase ref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_up);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_pick);
        ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);
        bus = new Bus();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        getCurrentLocation();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        if (!checkPermission()) {
            requestPermission();
        }

        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        if (location != null) {

            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();

            moveMap();
        }
    }

    private void moveMap() {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    }

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PickUpActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void requestPermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(PickUpActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            Toast.makeText(PickUpActivity.this, "GPS permission allows us to access location data. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PickUpActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getCurrentLocation();
                } else {

                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btn) {
            if (marker == null) {
                Toast.makeText(PickUpActivity.this, "Please Select Any Place", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                bus.setlatitude(marker_latitude);
                bus.setlongitude(marker_longitude);
                ref.child("school1").child("bus1").child("parents").child("parent01").child("pickuppoint").setValue(bus);
                Toast.makeText(PickUpActivity.this, "Pick Up Point Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        mMap.clear();
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng) //setting position
                .draggable(true) //Making the marker draggable
                .title("" + latLng));
        marker_latitude = latLng.latitude;
        marker_longitude = latLng.longitude;
    }
}
```

During analysis I found problem in below code:

```
bus.setlatitude(marker_latitude);
bus.setlongitude(marker_longitude);
   ref.child("school1").child("bus1").child("parents").child("parent01").child("pickuppoint").setValue(bus);
```

If I put some static value on `bus.setlatitude()` and `bus.setlongitude` no re-transition occur. I don't know what I am doing wrong and what is solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

if your user click on your Map the map will be cleared: `mMap.clear();`

```
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng) //setting position
            .draggable(true) //Making the marker draggable
            .title(""+latLng));
    marker_latitude = latLng.latitude;
    marker_longitude= latLng.longitude;

}
```

Comment: OK i will remove mMap.clear(); but problem still remaining.not be solve after removing

Comment: i'm not sure i understand ur problem correctly, but you don't define a new marker. your 'old' marker will be moved to the new place. you have to define a new marker every time. i updated my answer

now there should be added a new marker on the map on every click.

Comment: Ya i want to move one marker in all user click places . basically i was take one place for user which  was its pickup point.and lets't me more clear about my problem is for example take one activity name is MainActivity put one button on this activity .on this button click pass intent like this "startactivity(new Intent(MainActivity.This,MainActivity.class));" and show what happen on this button click aczetly happen like this without write such type of code and more thing which i was noted when i was pass static parameter as above mention everything gone be fine.